# solid communication methods for a docking robot

Tags: serial, communication

I have a simple robot which drives along a track and waters plants. After each watering mission, it should return to its dock for further instructions. The dock has a Raspberry Pi, while the robot uses an Arduino Pro Mini clone.

When the robot is at the dock, it connects to the pi using pogo-pins to form a serial connection.

[image]

Sometimes, the connection is not good - one or more pins are not connecting.

What other ways are there to form a serial connection, or what would you recommend?

Comment: I'm toying with the idea of adding an anchor - a hook which connects to the port wall to make sure the robot doesn't drift away from the pins, with an actuator which disconnects it before it sets off on its next watering mission

I would *prefer* to just do it the "right" way, whatever that is.

Comment: after further thinking, maybe I don't need serial at all? I'm mostly using it because this is a development robot and I sometimes need to reprogram the arduino in the robot (through the pins), but I have read that it's possible to program an arduino remotely using an HCL-05 bluetooth module, so that might be a workaround.

this way there are only two pins left to worry about - VCC and ground - for charging the battery.

Comment: What is the pogo pin mating with? You could try adding a magnetic coupler that would keep tension on the pogo pins and then pull off when the bot drives away. There should be plenty of torque on your motors to disengage a couple 6 mm magnets.

Comment: at the moment, they are mating with some bolt heads. I "tune" the bolt head distances by simply screwing them in or out.

magnets are very probably the correct solution

Comment: perhaps the communication link could be optical

Comment: that's what the HCL-05 idea was about - it uses non-visible light, but is not directional so there's one less headache to solve. I'll use a magnetic coupler on the VCC and ground lines so there's a solid power connection at the port, and bluetooth to form a non-physical communication link

Comment: Some connectors have "insertion detection". One way to implement this is have extra pins on the left and right ends that are shorted together on the dock side (perhaps all 4 are grounded). On the robot side, the outer pins are grounded, and their neighboring detection pins have pullup resistors. When the robot fails to detect that both the left and right detection pins are grounded, it backs up and tries to make contact again.

Comment: Is it possible to tilt the pogo pins, allowing contact wiping surface cleaning between the pins as they are compressed against the bolt head opposite contact? ( https://www.pvdijk.com/pdf/21thiceccriticalaspects.pdf )

Comment: I really like that pin-shorting idea. if I keep those pins slightly shorter than the rest by 0.5mm or so, that should ensure that the robot presses right up against the port